# UIRefreshControl sticks up at top of table

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm using `UIRefreshControl` in `UITableviewController`. The first time the table loads data coming from internet it automatically shows up at the top. See image below.
[image]

This is how I'm setting my refresh control

```
[self.refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(doRefresh:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
- (void)doRefresh:(CKRefreshControl *)sender {
    NSLog(@"Refreshing Parent");
    // bring Data Here
}
```

This all happens before pull-to-refresh. First time when simple table data is populated the refresh control is shown instead of being hidden under the navigation bar.
Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

Comment: Please edit your question to include your code for creating and using the `UIRefreshControl`.

Comment: UITableViewController is made with xib file so I just set an action method for UIRefreshControl on ValueChnaged Method. I enable Refreshing in XIb also.

Comment: post some code when you call the method

Comment: This all happens before pull-to-refresh. First time when simple table data is poulated the refreshcontrol is shown instead of being hidden under nav bar.

Answer (score 0):

Try Allocating a new UIRefreshControl object and set the self.refreshControl to it. Something like that:

```
UIRefreshControl *refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
[refreshControl setAttributedTitle:[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Refreshing.."]];
[refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(doSomething:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
self.refreshControl = refreshControl;
```

Hope it helps.

EDIT: Also you should use [self.refreshControl endRefreshing] at the end of the invoked selector.

Comment: why? when I have refreshControl already from UITableviewController?

Comment: @AbidHussain because the refreshControl from the UITableViewController is not allocated when you initialize the Controller. You have to allocate and initialize new UIRefreshControl and assign it to the UITableViewController property. EDIT: You are right though, you can allocate it directly without creating an object -> self.refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init]